# Django 1.7 matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-1.7

I have the following error when I try to create a class-based view to Modify my model Destino. 
If possible I would do without using slug or pk in the urls.py

Error:

```
Destino matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8002/modificarVC/modificar.html
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Destino matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7-      py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 357
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/juanma/Escritorio/exPWfebrero/Django/AgenciaViajes',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

URLS:

```
url(r'^modificarVC/modificar.html', modificarVC.as_view(), name='modificarDestino'),
```

VIEWS:

```
class modificarVC(UpdateView):
    model = Destino
    template_name = "modificarVC/modificar.html"
    success_url = '/'

    def get_object(self):
        return Destino.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get('pk'))
```

Comment: Are you passing the pk at the querystring? `http://localhost:8002/modificarVC/modificar.html?pk=4`

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are trying to get the primary key from the querystring? The usual approach would be to include the primary key in the url e.g. `url(r'^modificarVC/(?<pk>\d+)/modificar.html', modificarVC.as_view(), name='modificarDestino'),`. Then you don't have to override `get_object` in your view.

Comment: And why are you including the `.html` extension in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in some comments, you've done a few things that go against the power of class based views. In regards to the [UpdateView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.7/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) which you're using, it's expecting a pk to be passed in.

```
# urls.py
url(r'^modificarVC/modificar/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', modificarVC.as_view(), name='modificarDestino')
```

When you hit a URL such as `/modificarVC/modificar/5/` the UpdateView automatically sets the object by selected the object in your model `Destino` that has an id of 5.

```
# views.py
class modificarVC(UpdateView):
    model = Destino
    template_name = "modificarVC/modificar.html"
    success_url = '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

your error message hints at problem -- your request url didn't include a 'pk' request parameter (see 'Request URL')

```
Destino matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8002/modificarVC/modificar.html
```

run your request again, but add the pk parameter to the end as a query parameter: http://localhost:8002/modificarVC/modificar.html?pk=42